# python fsolve: 'list' object is not callable

Tags: python, scipy

I seem to be having a problem with `scipy.optimize.fsolve()`. The error message is:

```
TypeError: 'list' object is not callable.
```

Code:

```
def eqs(P, z1):

    x1 = z1[0]
    y1 = z1[1]
    x2 = 1 - x1 
    y2 = 1 - y1

    fl1 = Fug(0, fsolve(PR(x1, P), 0.5), x1, P)
    fl2 = Fug(1, fsolve(PR(x1, P), 0.5), x2, P)
    fg1 = Fug(0, fsolve(PR(y1, P), 150), y1, P)
    fg2 = Fug(1, fsolve(PR(y1, P), 150), y2, P)

    error = (x1*fl1 - y1*fg1) + ((1-x1)*fl2 - (1-y1)*fg2)
    phiphi = x1*fl1 - y1*fg1

return [phiphi, error]


def main():

    P = 18
    x1 = (19.99 - P) / (19.99 - 3.59)
    y1 = IdealCase_y1(x1)
    z1 = [x1, y1]

    soln = fsolve(eqs(P, z1), z1)   
    x1, y1 = soln

return soln
```

I have used lists(The one with []'s) in fsolve before without a problem, so I'm unsure as to where to look for the problem.

The functions `eqs(P, z1)`, and thus Fug(...), as well as `IdealCase_y1` run without a problem, however when running `main()`, python returns the above mentioned error. The idea is to create a function `main()` which I can input different P values and return x1, y1 as output. the x1 = ... in main is an "informed guess", to tell `fsolve` where to look, and a `y1` guess is then generated from that value.

edit: IdealCase_y1(x1) is a function used to estimate the value of y1 required by fsolve. The  traceback is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\spyderlib\widgets\externalshell\sitecustomize.py", line 540, in runfile
execfile(filename, namespace)
  File "C:/Users/ShahuN/Documents/Project/q2_v0.3.py", line 229, in <module>
test = main()
  File "C:/Users/ShahuN/Documents/Project/q2_v0.3.py", line 223, in main
soln = fsolve(eqs(P, z1), [x1, y1])   
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\minpack.py", line 140, in fsolve
    res = _root_hybr(func, x0, args, jac=fprime, **options)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\minpack.py", line 197, in _root_hybr
    shape, dtype = _check_func('fsolve', 'func', func, x0, args, n, (n,))
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\minpack.py", line 20, in _check_func
     res = atleast_1d(thefunc(*((x0[:numinputs],) + args)))
 TypeError: 'list' object is not callable
```

if that's what is meant by the traceback.

Comment: Where is the traceback associated with the exception? What is `IdealCase_y1`?

Comment: If you are solving for z1, z1 should be the first argument in the function.

Answer (score 1):

```
soln = fsolve(eqs(P, z1), z1)
```

1)
 `func` should be a callable function.

2) 
the expected argument (optional) is `tuple` not list, you have to convert your list to tuple when you invoke `fsolve()`

```
scipy.optimize.fsolve(func, x0, args=(), fprime=None, full_output=0, col_deriv=0, xtol=1.49012e-08, maxfev=0, band=None, epsfcn=None, factor=100, diag=None)[source]

func : callable f(x, *args)
A function that takes at least one (possibly vector) argument.

args : tuple, optional
Any extra arguments to func.
```

**Edit:**
You invoke your function `eqs` in a wrong way, it should look like this:

```
soln = fsolve(eqs, P, args=(z1))
x1, y1 = soln
```

Comment: I have added tuple(...) to the return line of the list of the function eqs(P, z1) as well as inside the fsolve function inside main() so that they look like this: `return tuple([phiphi, error])` and `soln = fsolve(eqs(P, z1), tuple(z1)) `. The only difference is now python responds with `TypeError: 'tuple' object is not callable`. @haifzhan

Comment: I'd upvote that answer, but I'm new so I don't have the rep. Thank you, altough I am receiving an error somewhere completely diferent in the code now. Will investigate and post another question if need be.