# Python fmin_powell: 'tuple' object is not callable

Tags: python, machine-learning, scipy-optimize

Somewhat similar query to [python fsolve: 'list' object is not callable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30378242/python-fsolve-list-object-is-not-callable), however, that question didn't really help me. I'm trying to learn how to code some machine learning models and I have a typeError.

Code:

```
def cost_fun(self, lam, x, theta, m):
    """
    :type lam: int
    :type x: numpy.ndarray
    :type theta: numpy.ndarray 
    :type m: int
    """
    # sigmoid is simply a sigmoid function
    hyp = np.transpose(sigmoid(np.transpose(theta) * x))
    J = np.dot(-self.y, np.transpose(np.log(hyp))) - \
        (np.dot(1 - self.y,
                np.transpose(np.log(1 - hyp))) / m) + \
        np.dot((sum(theta ** 2) - theta[0] ** 2), lam / (2 * m))

    grad = np.transpose(np.dot(np.transpose(np.divide(x, m // 2)),
                        np.transpose((hyp - self.y)))) + \
        (np.dot(theta, lam) / (m // 2))

    grad[0] = 1 / m * sum(np.transpose(hyp - self.y) * x[0])

    return J, grad


def grad_desc(self, lam):
    """
    :type lam: int
    :type params: numpy.ndarray
    """
    min_theta1 = fmin_powell(
        self.cost_fun(lam, self.x, self.params, self.m), self.params
    )
```

Here is my traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Michael/OneDrive/Desktop/machinelearning.py", line 133, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:/Users/Michael/OneDrive/Desktop/machinelearning.py", line 17, in main
    ai.train(lam=5)
  File "C:/Users/Michael/OneDrive/Desktop/machinelearning.py", line 126, in train
    self.grad_desc(lam)
  File "C:/Users/Michael/OneDrive/Desktop/machinelearning.py", line 111, in grad_desc
    self.cost_fun(lam, self.x, self.params, self.m), self.params
  File "C:\Users\Michael\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\optimize.py", line 2558, in fmin_powell
    res = _minimize_powell(func, x0, args, callback=callback, **opts)
  File "C:\Users\Michael\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\optimize.py", line 2631, in _minimize_powell
    fval = squeeze(func(x))
  File "C:\Users\Michael\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\optimize.py", line 327, in function_wrapper
    return function(*(wrapper_args + args))
TypeError: 'tuple' object is not callable
Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: What are you trying to do in this line?     
min_theta1 = fmin_powell(self.cost_fun(lam, self.x, self.params, self.m), self.params)? Doesn't pass the smell test on how to properly call another class funciton.

Comment: It's meant to be a gradient descent algorithm to reduce theta.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Note that your `cost_fun` returns a tuple while `fmin_powell` expects a function that returns a scalar.

Comment: Thank you Joni and I'll keep that in mind for any future questions.